# SVN Firefox Plugin

Tags: svn, plugins, firefox-addon

Is there a firefox plugin which functions as an SVN client? I have checked on the official addon website. I really do not wish to go to the trouble of installing a standalone client, so is there currently a firefox plugin or some easy way I or someone else could make one? This would be very useful to me.

Comment: I think installing TortoiseSVN is probably less effort than posting here and waiting for answers...

Comment: Er, okay...Can it be installed externally on a flash drive?

Comment: You might wonder why there is no browser plugin but the reason is simple: SVN is a file-based system and therefore integration in the shell / file manager offers the best user experience.

Comment: What about Linux or Mac? Does TortoiseSVN work on Linux? I dont think so.

Comment: @Nachiket In Linux, there is [RabbitVCS](http://www.rabbitvcs.org/) which is quite similar to TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this firefox SVN extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3416), but it is basically just a shortcut to access [**TortoiseSVN**](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).

By itself, Tortoise is integrated into the shell, and very easy to use.

Comment: Okay, thanks, but I honestly would prefer something which does not require additional installation. If I cannot find/make something which would accomplish this, I guess I could go ahead and install TortoiseSVN and the ff extension.

Answer (score 2):

Install the SVN plugin in IE. Then Install the IE Tab plugin.

In Tools, IE Tab Options, select "always use current engine to open a new URL". Browse to any page, right click and select "open in IE Tab". Now enter the svn:\ url and display the page. Bookmark the page.

To open the svn page again, right click on the bookmark and select "open in IE Tab".

If you always use bookmarks, You may de-select "always use current engine to open a new URL"

Answer (score 1):

For reading and downloading files from a repository, you just can use any web-browser
and from Subversion 1.6 it even possible to see other revisions than HEAD.
However you are not able to see log messages or changesets, also you are not able to checkout or commit files, however I doubt that a webclient is the right tool for it.

Addition: 
You can also use the webDAV functionality to write directly to files inside your repository
(Autoversioning, see [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.webdav.autoversioning.html) for details)

Also there are a lot of svn-webclients you can use within your browser
Here are two projects:
http://www.websvn.info/

Polarion WebClient for SVN  supports also adding files and changing via download/upload cycle(do not know for websvn)http://community.polarion.com/index.php?page=overview&project=svnwebclient

Comment: Can you give a link to an svn webclient? And I know there are things like Trac you can use, but there is no way to checkout or commit files, as you said. Are there any webclients that do have that ability?

Comment: I added URLs and I mentioned the webDAV autoversioning

Answer (score 1):

From your comments it seems to me you're more interested in getting something that don't require an installation, and can be run from a flash drive.

One possibility for this is using the commandline client:
http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/

It comes in a .exe installer, but you can just unpack it (I used 7-zip, not sure if that matters) and run it from any folder.

There's also several other clients listed here, maybe you can find one that suits your tastes:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients